# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder

Spyder(python 3.7)

I am facing following errors here. I have already update all library from anaconda prompt. But can't findout the solution of the problem.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()

X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-4-05deb1f02719>", line 2, in <module>
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

Answer (score 30):

So based on your code, you'd have to:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Country column
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Country", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)

# Male/Female
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
```

Noticed how the first LabelEncoder was removed, you do not need to apply both the label encoded and the one hot encoder on the column anymore.

(I've kinda assumed your example came from the ML Udemy course, and the first column was a list of countries, while the second one a male/female binary choice)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Thanks, Antoine! Stay safe!

Comment: i'm working thru the ML Udemy course and the column transformer pulls the geography column and inserts 3 columns at the beginning of the ndarray. this leads to the labelencoder needing to be passed and index of 4 instead of 2. Is there a cleaner way to manage indexes, maybe using DataFrame instead of a ndarray?

Comment: I got the same issue. While using the solution provided, the type of the X object remains 'array' while we expect a 'float64' object I assume. Should this to be fixed ?

Answer (score 7):

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])],     remainder='passthrough')
    X=np.array(columnTransformer.fit_transform(X),dtype=np.str)
```

Since the latest build of sklearn library removed **categorical_features** parameter for onehotencoder class. It is advised to use ColumnTransformer class for categorical datasets. Refer the sklearn's official documentation for futher clarifications.

Comment: Yes, but: What does this add to other answers, including [Antoine Jaussoin's top-voted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59614780/3789665)?

Answer (score 4):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

label_encoder_x_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[: , 2] = label_encoder_x_1.fit_transform(X[:,2])
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("OneHot",        # Just a name
         OneHotEncoder(), # The transformer class
         [1]              # The column(s) to be applied on.
         )
    ],
    remainder='passthrough' # donot apply anything to the remaining columns
)
X = transformer.fit_transform(X.tolist())
X = X.astype('float64')
```

working like charm :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#) this is the [`__init__`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) line:

```
class sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', drop=None, sparse=True, dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='error')
```

As you can see the init does not get the variable `categorical_features`

You have an *categories* flag:

> categories‘auto’ or a list of array-like, default=’auto’
>   Categories (unique values) per feature:
>
> ‘auto’ : Determine categories automatically from the training data.
>
> list : categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column.
>   The passed categories should not mix strings and numeric values within
>   a single feature, and should be sorted in case of numeric values.
>
> The used categories can be found in the *categories_* attribute.
>
> **Attributes:** *categories_list* of arrays The categories of each feature
>   determined during fitting (in order of the features in X and
>   corresponding with the output of transform). This includes the
>   category specified in drop (if any).

Comment: How can I use categorical features in OneHotEncoder ? Please explain with an example

Comment: Same issue here, seems the API changed and I don't understand how to translate the old `categorical_features` to the new API.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is problem from ML course from Udemy
complete code
I did replaced label encoder 1 with column transformer as suggested by Antoine Jaussoin in above comment.

Categorical Data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Geography", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)
```

Your Gender column will have index 4 now

```
 labelencoder_x_2=LabelEncoder()
 X[:,4]=labelencoder_x_2.fit_transform(X[:,4])
```

to avoid dummy variable trap

```
 X=X[:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add call another class on sklearn which will eliminate 1 column to avoid dummies trap.

```
# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer # Here is the one

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

#onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1]) Not this one

# use this instead
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Country", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')

X = ct.fit_transform(X)
X = X[:, 1:])
```

Happy Helping!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Geography",OneHotEncoder(),[1])], remainder= 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)
labelencoder_X2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X2.fit_transform(X[:, 4])
X = X[: , 1:]
```

> X = np.array(X, dtype=float)

Just adding an extra line to convert it from array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code

```
# onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
# X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
# X = X[:, 1:]
```

with the following chunk and your code must

```
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()

X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(columnTransformer.fit_transform(X), dtype = np.float64)
X = X[:, 1:]
```

Assuming you're learning Deep Learning from udemy.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

# remove categorical_features, it works 100% perfectly
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is only one extension for onehotencoder.
if X have lot of columns.

## instead

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer([("encoder", OneHotEncoder(), list(categorical_features))], remainder = 'passthrough')

X = ct.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution including the transformation of the X object in array type in a float64 type

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

Answer (score 0):

`one_hot_encode = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])` is working for **scikit-learn 0.20.3** and the parameter removed from **scikit-learn 0.24.2** (versions I am checking).

Either Downgrade scikit-learn version
Or Use

````
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

"""2 classes- Known/unknown Face"""
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Faces", OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)

"""Country column"""
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Country", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest solution for the categorical_feature error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
Label_x = LabelEncoder()
x[:,0] = Label_x.fit_transform(x[:,0])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder.categorical_features =[0]
OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(x).toarray()
x = x[:, 1:]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).