# TypeError: OneHotEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run this using a csv file but this is giving an error and I have tried the answer given here: [TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476165/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-categorical-features) but that is not helping.I cannot figure out what to do here.

```
# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
# Encoding the Dependent Variable
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 24>()
     22 labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
     23 X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
---> 24 onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
     25 X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
     26 # Encoding the Dependent Variable

TypeError: OneHotEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneHotEncoder categorical\_features deprecated, how to transform specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-deprecated-how-to-transform-specific-column)

Comment: I dont think you are supposed to give it any parameters - when checking the docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html ...Can you not just fit_transform(X) with a blank OneHotEncoder() ?

Answer (score 0):

The version of scikit-learn is different

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).